# MetaMask account balance not updating

Tags: erc-20

I've gone through with the debugger to make sure msg.sender is my metamask account and that it should be updating.

I'm messing with the [0xBitcoin](https://etherscan.io/token/0xb6ed7644c69416d67b522e20bc294a9a9b405b31) ERC20 contract.

```
function myfunction() {
     balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(reward_amount)
     // My contract is 18 decimals but even after converting the amount to "ether"-like
     // units the amount is still 2 digits long. So it's not that the update is too small

     emit Mint(msg.sender, reward_amount, epochCount, challengeNumber
}
```

Where Mint is defined as

```
event Mint(address indexed from, uint reward_amount, uint epochCount, bytes32 newChallengeNumber);
```

So in summary my account balance doesn't update and I've checked

1) message.sender value

2) reward_amount is large enough that it should be visible

3) the transaction is going to completion without any errors preventing it

What could be going wrong that I haven't considered?

---

Here's the entire function. It's basically straight from the 0xBitcoin contract cited above.

```
function Mint(uint256 nonce, bytes32 challenge_digest) public returns (bool success) {
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(challengeNumber, msg.sender, nonce));

        if (digest != challenge_digest) revert();

        if(uint256(digest) > miningTarget) revert();

        bytes32 solution = solutionForChallenge[challengeNumber];
        solutionForChallenge[challengeNumber] = digest;

        if(solution != 0x0) revert(); // same answer can't be awarded twice

        uint reward_amount = getMiningReward();

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(reward_amount);
        tokensMinted = tokensMinted.add(reward_amount);

        lastRewardTo = msg.sender;
        lastRewardAmount = reward_amount;
        lastRewardEthBlockNumber = block.number;

        _startNewMiningEpoch();

        emit Mint(msg.sender, reward_amount, epochCount, challengeNumber);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: "My contract is 18 decimals but even after converting the amount to "ether"-like units the amount is still 2 digits long. So it's not that the update is too small" - where exactly do you do that, what is the original amount and what is the amount after you apply this conversion?

Comment: @goodvibration I used Web3 to convert it from “wei” to “ether”. The amount was like 70 afterward. Wei is 10^18 ether so this just takes the number and divides it by 10^18. I know my contract isn’t technical ether

Comment: What is "afterward" in this context? What value are you passing to function `myfunction`? How are you executing this function? Please share the relevant web3 code.

Comment: You divide the amount by 10^18 before sending it to the contract??? That sounds grossly wrong. What does "my contract don’t technical ether" mean???

Comment: @goodvibration I used the debugger to figure out what value was being provided in remix. It was like 78230123901928310293 so I copied that number into a Jupyter Notebook that I've been using to interact with my contract. The function is  web3.fromWei(balance_wei, 'ether') where I passed in that large number for balance_wei. While my number doesn't represent wei but rather the currency being mined, the conversion is the same (divide by 10^18). So while I didn't divide the number in the contract, it's clear the number should have been big enough to register on my metamask account

Comment: Contracts don't know anything about wei, 18 decimals or anything like that. They take as input and return as output only integer values. MetaMask, on the other hand, does, and it displays information to you in units of 10^18. So, for example, when you pass a value smaller than 10^18, it will present it as a value smaller than 1. You should not take your input and divide it by 10^18 before passing it to the contract. If this input is in wei units, then you should pass as is. If it's in MetaMask units, then you should multiply it by 10^18 before psasing it to the contract.

Comment: Yeah I didn't divide it by 10^18, I left it alone, Dividing it by 10^18 was not part of the program, I just wanted to make sure that it being too small wasn't a reason for it not updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reason for wallets to not notice new tokens being minted is that they will only listen for `Transfer` event.

In the [ERC20 specification](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20#events) only `Transfer` event is defined.

For example [OpenZeppelin's implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L174-L182) generates a `Transfer` with sender being the null address `0x00000000...00`.

```
emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
```